# IBM Bluemix Single Sign On (SSO) import metadata error FBTRBA331E

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud, saml

We have a Single Sign On service connects to our Node.js app on IBM Bluemix. We need to use SAML Enterprise as our identify source. When I upload the SAML 2.0 Identity Provider metadata file - I get the error saying:

Error executing REST service.

FBTRBA331E The action: Import Metadata failed because the metadata file or federation role is invalid.
[image]

I also found the error code from another IBM page, but it doesn't say how to fix it.
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSELE6_8.0.1.3/com.ibm.isam.doc/messages/messages/FBTRBA331E.html

Comment: How are you using SSO? What kind of application are you using it with? Please provide the code you were running to give some context for why you are getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

According to this Bluemix SSO document (scroll down to the SAML metadata files section):

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SingleSignOn/saml_information.html#saml_information

IdP (Identify Provider) metadata file must contain both Signing and Encryption Key sections. If the encryption certificate is missing, you see an upload error indicating that the format of the metadata file is wrong or that improper federation roles exist.

Both of the following KeyDescriptor sections are required.

```
<md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
<KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<X509Data>
<X509Certificate>(...signing certificate...)</X509Certificate>
</X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
</md:KeyDescriptor>

<md:KeyDescriptor use="encryption">
<KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<X509Data>
<X509Certificate>(...encryption certificate...)</X509Certificate>
</X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
<md:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5"/>
</md:KeyDescriptor>
```

Please double check the metadata file you received from your Identity Provider to see if the encryption section is missing.